# TeXMaker compile options 1-5

Tags: compiling, texmaker

In the toolbar of TeXMaker there is a scroll-bar with different build/compile options. This is where you can use "Quick build" easily. If you scroll down you find numbers (see picture). Is there a way to set these up to do different combinations of compiling functions, for example

1:`LaTeX -> BibTeX -> LaTeX -> LaTeX -> View PDF`

2:`LaTeX -> MakeIndex -> LaTeX -> LaTeX -> View PDF`

3:`LaTeX -> View PDF`

[image: The Scroll bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attached two screenshots which explain how to edit the so-called **user commands** in Texmaker.

[image]

[image]